# Python code for Debye theory gives a syntax error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this code that I typed into Python and I'm getting "Syntax error: invalid syntax" for b=Od/T. Does it have to do with how it's defined? How can I fix it

```
import scipy.integrate as sci
import scipy.constant as scc
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from IPython import get_ipython
get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')

def f(T):
    n=6.022*(10**28)
    Od=429
    V=10**(-3)
    ft=lambda x: ((x**4)*math.exp(x)/(((math.exp(x))-1**2))

    b = Od/T
    a=0

    C=9*V*n((T/Od)**3)*scc.k*(sci.quad(ft,a, b.any(),limit=10))[0]
    return C

T1=np.arange(5,500,1)

plt.plot(T1,f(T1),'r-')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a closing parentheses on the previous line:

```
ft=lambda x: ((x**4)*math.exp(x)/(((math.exp(x))-1**2))
           # ^ This parenthesis is never closed.
```

Comment: Took out the parenthesis and now it says: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy.constant'

Comment: @NotEinstein: That's a separate problem that should be posed as a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

Error in the line before that. You can try this.

```
fr=lambda x: (x**4)*math.exp(x)/((math.exp(x))-1**2)
```